# jquery mobile - enterprise scalable solution?

Tags: jquery, iphone, mobile

We are creating a user interface that functions on a wide variety of platforms with minimal loss of function. The idea is to code an intuitive design using the lowest common denominator - in this case, the device with the lowest functionality. Using the iPhone as an example (compared to the larger screen size of the iPad or desktop), we have elected to use jquery mobile as our platform of choice. Jquery mobile allows keeping separate CSS markup tags so the underlying data structures can remain the same while the presentation on screen can be tailored to different screen sizes.

My question is will this approach continue to be tenable as the number of users and types of devices continue to change? Is it easier to simply create a separate mobile site, even though this will lead to different user interfaces over time and generate confusion with end users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes jQuery mobile great for your particular scenario is that sites created using jquery mobile (in my experience) run beautifully on both desktop and mobile browsers. Their purpose is to make cross-platform web sites/apps so they will most likely grow with the devices that come on the market. It may take a bit of tweaking to work the way you like it, but the end result (for me at least) was stellar.